# Java Com4j interface for Abbyy on win7 64bit

Tags: java, com4j, abbyy

I’m currently trying to upgrade à Java solution using ABBY OCR from Windows XP 32bit to Windows 7 64bit. A bridge using com4j exist between the two. Generation of the new interphases works well, but use it or the older generate this stack trace:

```
com4j.ComException: 8000ffff Défaillance irrémédiable : Erreur programme interne:
.\src\RegExpPreprocessor.cpp, 53. : .\invoke.cpp:517
at com4j.Wrapper.invoke(Wrapper.java:166)
at $Proxy97.recognizeNextDocument(Unknown Source)
at net.atos.FraudeDocumentaire.engine.EngineAbbyy.analyseDocument(EngineAbbyy.java:202)
at net.atos.FraudeDocumentaire.engine.ThreadIdentification.run(ThreadIdentification.java:40)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com4j.ComException: 8000ffff Défaillance irrémédiable : Erreur programme interne:
.\src\RegExpPreprocessor.cpp, 53. : .\invoke.cpp:517
at com4j.Native.invoke(Native Method)
at com4j.StandardComMethod.invoke(StandardComMethod.java:35)
at com4j.Wrapper$InvocationThunk.call(Wrapper.java:340)
at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)
at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)
at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)
```

Have you any idea where problem come from ? Did you think it’s ABBYY internal faillure or com4j?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score -1):

The error `.\src\RegExpPreprocessor.cpp`, 53 looks like an ABBYY FineReader Engine internal error. Please contact ABBYY technical support at SDK_Support@abbyy.com .

By the way latest ABBYY FineReader Engine Distribution Kit contains its own Java wrapper – `com.abbyy.FREngine.jar`. You can try using it instead of com4j. You'll need `CreateEngineOutprocLoader` method to load Engine in а 64bit process.

We also recommend you to read the article "Using ABBYY FineReader Engine in Java" in the ABBYY FineReader Engine Help.